# How do i store the value "total " outside the loop?

Tags: java

I am writing my first game on java and I am having difficulties with storing 1 value after the loop ends.

```
int dice1, dice2, count, total = 0, total1 = 0;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Press /y again");
String response = "";
response = scan.next();

//while loop for player dice
while (response.equals("y")) { 
   System.out.println("Roll dice? y/n");
   response = scan.next();
   if (response.equals("n")) {
       ComputerPig.ComputerRoll();
   }
   Random rand = new Random();
   dice1 = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
   dice2 = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
   count = (dice1 + dice2);
   total += count; // i need to store this value
```

Comment: _Where_ do you want to store it? _What_ do you want to use the value for? And _where_ (in what context) is the code you posted called?

Comment: You have declared outside the loop and incrementing it inside the loop. Why `total` would not store the value outside the loop?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your problem is.  You're already declaring `total` external to your while loop.

Comment: I don't know what exactly is the problem, but every time i run the loop total resets and starts from 0. I need to store it as a total score of dices because the purpose of the game is to reach 100 points.

Comment: How do you "run the loop"?  You haven't included anything about where this code lives or how it is invoked in your question, which makes it rather difficult for anyone to give advice about that.

Comment: Are you actually getting in to that loop? You may want to look at how you are scanning in your response. Try using scan.nextLine() instead of next()

Comment: where is this code being executed from and where are you trying to access the value from after it is executed.

Comment: Assuming by saying "every time i run the loop" you mean you execute the _entire_ block you posted each "run" then it's clear: you recreate `total` and initialize it to 0 with each "run". Without any more information it's hard to help, as there are many options: return it from the method you're calling, store it in some object etc. - which is feasible for you depends on your design choices.

Answer (score 0):

For one, you need to break out of the loop once the user enters n

```
if (response.equals("n")) {
       ComputerPig.ComputerRoll();
       break;
   }
```

For two, I tested this code, minus the `ComputerPig.ComputerRoll();` and it worked fine for me. When I entered `n` it went into the if statement above, then exited out of the `while` loop, and I printed the total at the bottom. So your code is correct. `total` is stored when the loop ends, you have a problem somewhere else.